# Why is props not passed to child component Route React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I'm trying to build a SPA with ReactJS, and i have a problem when getting url params.
Can you explanin to me that the difference between 2 methods below.

```
<Route exact path="/blog/:slug.:id" component={BlogDetail}/>
-------------------------------------------------------
<Route exact path="/blog/:slug.:id">
 <BlogDetail/>
</Route>
```

With the first method, i can get slug and id from props in **BlogDetail Component**. But the second is not.
Why?
Please help me :D
Sorry about my english if it isn't good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route`'s `component` is a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#use-render-props-for-cross-cutting-concerns). Having a render prop will guarantee that `props` are passed down to the rendered component which is the case in the first method. This however is encapsulated within the `Route` component.

The second method however, `BlogDetail` is a child to `Route`. To be able to use route props, it should be explicitly passed to the child component.

Comment: So how i can pass props to child component?